# How can I resolve this error in vscode output? I already tried npm install

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

Info: Start process (2:00:25 AM)
Error:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:317
    throw e;
    ^

SyntaxError: Error parsing /Users//package.json: Unexpected token   in JSON at position 121
    at parse (<anonymous>)
    at readPackage (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:304:20)
    at readPackageScope (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:329:19)
    at shouldUseESMLoader (node:internal/modules/run_main:43:15)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:72:24)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
```

Comment: what module is this, can you add your package.json

Comment: Check for typos in package,json.

Answer (score -1):

Share your package.json file. The json data in the file is invalid.

Comment: this should be a comment